# If someone modifies and builds my flutter application, will it be able to connect to my Firebase backend?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I'm developing a mobile app using flutter. I want to make it open-source. However, I have the following concerns:

- someone can easily fork my repo, and change the client code, and somehow gain access to some premium features

Can I prevent this by any chance? What came to my mind is, maybe I can somehow make my firebase-backend accept connections only from applications signed by me? Maybe it is already like this. I'm not very familiar with signing the application for android and iOS.

**If I can make the builds lose access to my server if they are not built by me, that would be enough for me.**

Any help or clarification on the topic is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Firebase, all configuration data needed to access the backend services is present in your app itself (otherwise *that* also couldn't call those services).

The easiest way to prevent other apps from calling your backend services is to [enable App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) on your app, which ensures only your own code/app on a genuine device can call the backend services.

Also see:

- [How to allow only my app to access firebase without a login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395025/how-to-allow-only-my-app-to-access-firebase-without-a-login), specifically [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441673/209103) to it.
- My answer to [Restrict access to Firebase storage so only my app can access it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611884/209103)

Comment: my follow-up question would be: what do we mean by "only your own code/app on a genuine device"? And how does app check can verify it? 
I know that all the data in the apk and ios bundle can be somehow extracted (including firebase config). So, if someone forks my codebase, and builds the apk, and installs that apk on their android device, how App Check can detect it's not my code?

Comment: I guess, for android, when I use play-app-signing, if someone alters the code, the signature won't hold anymore, and the attestation will fail. It is probably more or less the same with iOS. Is this the main reason why AppCheck works?

Comment: App Check works with on-device attestation providers for mobile, and re-CAPTCHA for web. The documentation probably has a better explanation of how that works, than I can give here. :)

Comment: Please take a look at the package freeRASP. I believe it will help you alleviate your concerns. Package is frequently updated and the GH issues are also monitored and responded. https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp